# How to get alert and value when click on option from select tag using jQuery method

Tags: jquery

I have select tag with multiple options so when I click on particular option by using its class name I want alert box and value should  get  but using only click event not using onChange event in jQuery script

```js
$('.clk-option').on('click', function () {
  alert();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option class="clk-option" value="value2">value2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".clk-option").click(function(){
        alert("The button was clicked.");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select>
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option class="clk-option" value="value2">value2</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Source :

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp

Comment: i tried your code but it is not working I mean didn't get any alert

Comment: You can see the error in the console of your browser. How do you insert your script... without these informations it's to hard to say why it's not working.

Comment: no console error  in script it is fine but surprise why this  is not working

Comment: I edit my post to reflect script insertion in a page.

Answer (score 0):

For get the value, you can use the jQuery [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method, check next example.

```js
$('.clk-option').on('click', function ()
{
    var value = $(this).attr("value");
    alert("Value of the option is: " + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option class="clk-option" value="value2">value2</option>
</select>
```

For versions of JQuery greater or equal than **1.6** you can use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method too:

```js
$('.clk-option').on('click', function ()
{
    var value = $(this).prop("value");
    alert("Value of the option is: " + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option class="clk-option" value="value2">value2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('select').on('change', function () {
  //console.log($(this).val(), $('select option:selected').attr('class'));
  if ($('select option:selected').attr('class') === "clk-option") {
    // ---- put your conditional code here
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option class="clk-option" value="value2">value2</option>
</select>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Did you read the question, he explicity says don't wanted to use the `onChange` event.

Comment: @Shiladitya I want this using on click because onchange script used for other task so please suggest me using only click event

Comment: @MSP Click has been depreciated, you won't capture the click event at least in **Chrome**. I would request you to tweak you code and make it happen with onChange event